# Showing div based on select option

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm trying to show div based on selected option in dropdown.It's work with option `1` and `2` but when I selected second option it showing third `div`.

```js
function valueNew(ele) {
  // get all div with class name 'div'
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
  // iterating over them and hidding all
  for( var i=0;i<div.length;i++) {
    div[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
  // getting div which is need to show using value of selected option
  div[ele.value].style.display = 'block';
}

// trigger change event to show default div
document.getElementById('sel').onchange();
```

```html
<select id="sel" onChange="valueNew(this)">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option vlaue="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>

<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px; display:none">1</div>
<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">2</div>
<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">3</div>
```

Comment: I would probably move `var div = document.getElementsByClassName('div');` outside of the function. There's no need to collect all the elements each time you make a selection.

Comment: @Andy : thanks good suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typo mistake:

```
 <option vlaue="1">2</option>
```

Change it with:

```
 <option value="1">2</option>
```

See it working:

```js
function valueNew(ele) {
  // get all div with class name 'div'
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
  // iterating over them and hidding all
  for( var i=0;i<div.length;i++) {
    div[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
  // getting div which is need to show using value of selected option
  div[ele.value].style.display = 'block';
}

// trigger change event to show default div
document.getElementById('sel').onchange();
```

```html
<select id="sel" onChange="valueNew(this)">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>

<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px; display:none">1</div>
<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">2</div>
<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">3</div>
```

Comment: Yes, sometimes we need a second opinion because we have the eyes broken. I understand you :)

Comment: Anyway thanks buddy :)